# Transparent status bar with expo and react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I've searched and tried many solutions, so my apologies if I missed a previous issue.

I'm using Expo and react-navigation stack navigator.

I want to have a fully transparent status bar, but still see the icons.

I was able to get the transparent status bar, but the navigator is too tall once I render the status bar (I assume because it is tall enough to factor in not having a status bar).

What's the best / easiest way to achieve this?

Do I need to change expo settings or handle it all in the code?

Comment: Please add [mcve] showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Add some padding at the top to fix it

Comment: Can I ask how you managed to get a transparent background in the first place?